# Equivalent Angular RouterOutlet in Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor

Angular has a RouterOutlet, which allows automatically change the content inside component 
depending on the route.

It seems that such an opportunity is not available in Blazor ...

How can I implement this in Blazor?

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t anything fancy built in, but you can do it using navigation manager or route binding.

1. Route binding

A page component can have multiple routes. You can take advantage of this for simple binary cases such as sharing logic between an add and edit page.

```
    @page "/modifyperson"
    @page "/modifyperson/{Id}"

    @if(isEdit)
    {
    }

    @code
    {
        [Parameter] 
        public string  Id {get; set;}
        bool isEdit;

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
                IsEdit=true;
        }
    }
```

2. Navigation Manager

```
    @page "/myfirstroute"
    @page "/mysecondroute"
    @inject NavigationManager navManager 
    @if(route==PageRoutes.FirstRoute)
    {
        //do something different
    }

    @code
    {
        public enum PageRoutes{FirstRoute,SecondRoute}
        private PageRoutes route;
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        { 
            string lastRouteInfo= navManager.Uri.Split("/").Last();
            if(lastRouteInfo=="myfirstroute")
                route=PageRoutes.FirstRoute;
            else if(lastRouteInfo=="mysecondroute")
                route =PageRoutes.SecondRoute;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that OnInitialized is not a good candidate for this scenario, you should really be using `SetParameters` or `SetParametersAsync` - See https://blazor-university.com/routing/optional-route-parameters/